# Is the category of prederivators cartesian closed?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory

The question is in the title. ${\bf PDer} = Fun({\bf Cat}^\text{op}, {\bf CAT})$ is obviously cartesian since $\bf CAT$ is. The usual argument for presheaf categories does not apply directly since 1-cells in $\bf PDer$ are  *pseudo*-natural transformations.

I can't find references for this (or reasons why it's false).

Comment: See section 2.3 of http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/~mgroth/groth_monoidal.pdf.

Comment: Ah, nice. I was looking in an older paper ("Monoidal derivators")